# Java.lang.illegalArgumentException While trying to run in Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have created a smiple Message Driven Bean PRoject and while trying to deploy and run it on server getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.jms.Queue field com.myservlet.MdbServlet.queue to com.sun.messaging.Topic
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:688)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:991)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could any one help me what would be the possible reason?

===========================================================================

Code from com.myservlet.MdbServlet.java:

```
package com.myservlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MdbServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/MdbServlet")
public class MdbServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/ConnFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/DestinationQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MdbServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String userMessage = request.getParameter("msg");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if (connectionFactory == null) {
            out.println("Connection Factory lookup has failed");
            return;
        }

        if (queue == null) {
            out.println("Queue lookup has failed");
            return;
        }
        Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText(userMessage);
            producer.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for com.myservlet.MdbServlet?

Comment: @ NamshubWriter: Updated code from com.myservlet.MdbServlet. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You have `jms/DestinationQueue` defined as a **Topic** rather than a **Queue**.  Look at your JMS configuration and rectify.  To test this theory, change `private Queue queue;` to `private Topic queue;` and try it out.

I suggest searching for `DestinationQueue` within your project to find out where you need to change this setting.